# If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, then $A$ is bounded.

Tags: general-topology

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, then $A$ is bounded.

here is my attempt
Let $\xi = \{C_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a covering by open sets of $A$, and let $x \in A$ be arbitrary. Note that open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are balls. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $A \subset \bigcup_{p \in A} B(p, \epsilon)$. Since $A$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering $\{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n\}$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} B(p_i, \epsilon)$. As $x \in A$, it follows that $x \in B(p_k, \epsilon)$ for some $1 \leq k \leq n$.

I did this, but I don't know if I am correct. I don't know how to conclude it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I cannot use metrics or sequences.

Comment: Instead of starting with arbitrary covering, pick an over cover that you can control and use compactness of $A$.

Comment: You correctly argued that each $x \in A$ is in some $B(p_k, \epsilon)$, however, from that you cannot conclude $A$ is bounded.  You want a *single* ball $B$ so that $A \subseteq B$.  Try a cover consisting of balls with progressively bigger radii.

Comment: Cover by $\mathbb{R}^n$ with balls with center at the origin, and larger and larger diameter.

Comment: What definition of "bounded" are you using? From what you've shown you can argue that there's a finite upper bound on the distance between any two points in $A$ (why?), from which it follows that $A$ is bounded. Note it's not true that all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are balls.

Comment: @blargoner Well, in this case, I'm not very sure about the definition I'm using, as I'm only relying on the definition of balls. It occurs to me that I can see that this union of balls is contained within a closed ball, and you are right not all open sets are balls

Comment: Arbitrary open sets aren’t necessarily balls.

Comment: anonymous is correct that you cannot assume some arbitrary open sets are balls. But that isn't necessary. You are not trying to prove something about arbitrary open covers. You are trying to prove that there is some $R$ such that $A \subseteq B(0, R)$. For that, you do not need an arbitrary open cover. A single very specific open cover will do.

Answer (score 0):

or maybe this one
Let $\xi = {C_i}{i \in I}$ be a covering by open sets of $A$, without loss of generality, we can assume that $A \subset \bigcup_{p \in A} B(0, p)$, which are balls centered at the origin. Since $A$ is compact, there exists a finite subcovering ${p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_n}$ such that $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} B(0, p_k)$. As every open ball is contained within a closed ball, let $p_j = max\{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$. Then $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{n} B(0, p_k) \subset B[0, p_j]$, which means that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $B(0,p)$ where $p$ is a point? By your own earlier usage, which is also common usage, $B(0, r)$ are balls of radius $r$, a real number, not a point. If you mean a ball with radius $|p|$, then your statement is false, as the union of these *open* balls will have contain the elements of compact $A$ that are farthest from the origin (the closure will contain $A$, but not the union itself). You don't need to choose radii tied to $A$. Just make the balls grow big enough $A$ is insude the union.